# font and color change not applying only to datepicker

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, calendar, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have created an application for getting a calendar using angularjs, I have used [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker) plugin for achieving that. The application is working fine but the issue is that I want he font size of the calendar to be `font-size: 105%` when I applied the below style it is applying to the full page.

```
 *, th, tr {
  font-size: 105% !important;
}
```

Also how can i change the default blue color of the calendar  My working demo is shown in the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zmhz8km/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply css on calendar table instead of all th element like
replace

```
*, th, tr {
  /* text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; */
  font-size: 105% !important;
}
```

by

```
.table-striped {
  /* text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; */
  font-size: 205% !important;
}
```

Comment: Which color you want to change??

Comment: @AlexMan Just give color in the above mentioned css i.e.                   .table-striped {
  /* text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; */
  font-size: 205% !important; color:#1ab394 !important;
}

Comment: that color is to be applied to the selection and not the date labels

Comment: add this css  td.active.active{
    color:#1ab394 !important;
}

Comment: @AlexMan you want font color to be changed or the background color. for background color add below css at the very last of your page (not 100% sure) if it works   td.active.active{ background-color:#1ab394  !important;
background-image:none !important;
} 
td.active.disabled:hover {
    background-color: #1ab394  !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

try to narrow it down by the datepicker selector itself:

```
#datepicker > *, th, tr {
  font-size: 105% !important;
}
```